# Multi Store and multi product magento

Tags: magento-1.9

How can i create multi store and every store have their own products.At the end, grouping the product in a specific groups or categories.Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create Different Root Category for each store then you need to create multi store then assign root category to store.

This tutorial will help you to create multi store and different root category https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-multiple-magento-storefronts.html

Note: Assign product as per store category so product will be visible for particular store as per your need.

Comment: thank for your reply but i don't think that what i'm looking for.On magento i can create multi store under the same website(that's what i need). i'm just trying to create multi store under the same website to prevent using multi website. then after creating multi store, the next step is to create products related to these stores. i think this will help me to reach my goal that i can group multi product under the same category.So the user who access my website can find different chooses.Ex: you can find multi products and have the same functionality with different brand under the same category.

Comment: Yes you can create multi store under same website. I am also talk about that. After creating multistore with same website, assign particular category group to particular store so you can differentiate products per store.